# C# linq, obtain most frequent item in collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections

i am trying to obtain an item from a collection that occurs most frequently. if i were in SQL i would do something like this..

```
select top(1) extension from database.table
group by extension
order by count(extension) desc
```

but im trying to do this using linq.

Can someone assist with the translation?

so far i have this but its not working...

```
string topExtension = (from c in extensions select c).GroupBy(d => d).OrderByDescending(e => e.Count()).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `FirstOrDefault` instead.

EDIT: Oops, sorry.  Try  `.FirstOrDefault().Key`.

Comment: same error... Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,string>' to 'string'

Comment: You should use .First() here .FirstOrDefault() can return null, which will cause a NullReferenceException on .Key.